# Calculate limit of sequence $a_{n+1} = 3-1/a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have been given the following problem:
$$
a_1 = 1, a_{n+1} = 3-\frac{1}{a_n}\\
\text{ Find: }\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n
$$
I have already proved that the function is always increasing and bounded by 3. So I know the sequence will converge. However, I have not learned how to compute limits for successor functions, nor do I know how to transform this into a function of n.

My math book tells me the answer is $(3+\sqrt5)/2$, though I do not know how they reached this answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now you know the limit exists, so you can assume it is $a$. Then take limit on both sides of
$$ a_{n+1}=3-\frac{1}{a_n}
$$
and you obtain:
$$ a=3-\frac{1}{a}
$$
Solve the equation, and you get two roots $\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and  $\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. You know the sequence is increasing and $a_1=1$ so $\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the correct limit.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: in the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $a_{n+1} \sim a_n$.

So set $a_{n+1}=a_n=a$.  Then

$$a=3-\frac{1}{a} \implies a^2-3 a+1=0 \implies a=\frac{3\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Which root is correct?  We want $a_n>1$ as befots the behavior of the sequence; the result follows.

Answer (score 3):

Let the limit be $a$. Then 
$$a=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(3-\frac{1}{a_n}\right)=3-\frac{1}{a}.$$

After simplifying, we get the quadratic equation $a^2-3a+1=0$. Solve.